React native app starting (app logs showing up in metro) but app does not show up in simulator
Trying to run a react-native app in ios.
After running react-native start and react-native run ios. The app is successfully compiling and launches the simulator. I can see app logs in the metro process so the app is indeed running. However the simulator doesn't actually launch the app. There are no errors.
Xcode: 15.4
React native: 0.72.4
node: v20.11.1
cocoapods: 1.15.2
ruby: 3.3.2
How can i go about debugging/solving this issue?
I tried reinstalling xcode and cocoapods and simulator data. I tried using a newer version of ruby. hoping it was a compatibility issue with react native.
Logs from the 'react-native run-ios' command:
▸ Build Succeeded
success Successfully built the app
2024-06-11 12:20:58.698 xcodebuild[56733:585428]  DVTPlugInQuery: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier 'Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition'. This is programmer error; code should only request extension points that are defined by itself or its dependencies.
info Installing "/var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-fmiylqugvdpoozhcqiygqbyxyoyi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app on iPhone 15 Pro Max"
info Launching "com.AwesomeProject"


success Successfully launched the app on the simulator

Logs from metro:

 LOG  Running "AwesomeProject" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}


what are the logs in metro and in the console ?

updated the question with logs.

Most likely, the application will open when you start the metro server and run the application in the simulator via Xcode. However, for testing purposes, can you try Product -> Clean Build Folder and yarn start --reset-cache?
